# Count number of order and order lines report

Tags: mysql

I want to generate a report to count number of orders and order_lines by monthly.

In the `orders` table I have `order_id` and `order_date` fields

In the `order_lines` table, I have `order_lines_id`, `order_id`

I want a report to generate like this:

```
Year, Month, NumberOfOrders, NumbersOfLines 
2015   1           4             55
2015   2           3             6
```

I have tried the following SQL and didn't work how I wanted to be

```
SELECT 
  Year(orders.order_date) as Year,
  Month(orders.order_date) as Month,
  count(orders.order_id) as NumberOfOrders, 
  count(order_lines.order_lines_id) as NumbersOfLines, 
FROM `orders`               
  LEFT JOIN order_lines On order_lines.orders_id = order_lines.order_lines_id
group by sales.sales_id, order_lines.order_lines_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work for two reasons, 1 - because you grouped it by the wrong values. Think about it, you want to aggregate for each Year,Month . Why did you group by salesid and orderlines id?

And 2- your left join condition is not correct, you need to compare the common column in both tables which in this case is order_id

Anyways, try this:

```
SELECT 
  Year(t.order_date) as Year,
  Month(t.order_date) as Month,
  count(distinct t.order_id) as NumberOfOrders, 
  count(order_lines.order_lines_id) as NumbersOfLines, 
FROM `orders` t               
  LEFT JOIN order_lines On t.order_id = order_lines.order_id
group by Year(t.order_date), Month(t.order_date)
```

or with correlated query:

```
SELECT 
  Year(t.order_date) as Year,
  Month(t.order_date) as Month,
  (select count(distinct s.order_id)
      from orders s
      where Year(t.order_date) = Year(s.order_date)
      and Month(t.order_date) = Month(s.order_date))  as NumberOfOrders, 
  count(order_lines.order_lines_id) as NumbersOfLines, 
FROM `orders` t               
  LEFT JOIN order_lines On t.order_id = order_lines.order_id
group by Year(t.order_date), Month(t.order_date)
```

Comment: Fast as an arrow! +1

Comment: Can anyone explain why did I get downvoted twice with the right answer?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I didn't thought you did, but I don't understand why I got two downvotes for this answer

Comment: Didn't seem to work. NumberOfOrders and NumbersOfLines have identical values. Usually an order can have many lines. So number of NumbersOfLines should be higher than NumberOfOrders

Comment: Please go back to your original answer, I missed `distinct` in count.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Both of the answers are in my answer, both should work the same